# C# Catch Events from Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, task

Here is the some code I wrote. The blah object's `Start` method runs an infinite loop and raises events if something happens. I have in my mind to catch the events using the code below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var blah = new Blah();

    blah.SomeEvent += Log;

    Task.Factory.Start(blah.Start);

    Application.Run();
}

static void Log(string text, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Will this work If I add more instances of the objects? I mean as far as I know tasks can run on a separate thread so the event might not be caught right?

Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why shouldn't it be caught? Just make sure to register for the event of all instances.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var blah = new Blah();

    blah.SomeEvent += Log;

    Task.Factory.Start(blah.Start);

    var blah2 = new Blah();

    blah2.SomeEvent += Log;

    Task.Factory.Start(blah2.Start);

    Application.Run();
}

static void Log(string text, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Will work the same and whenever one of the Blahs has something to log it will do it.
The problem lies in the fact whether your method Log() is threadsafe or not.
For instance if you log to a File you rather should use:

```
static object loglock = new object();
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var blah = new Blah();

    blah.SomeEvent += Log;

    Task.Factory.Start(blah.Start);

    var blah2 = new Blah();

    blah2.SomeEvent += Log;

    Task.Factory.Start(blah2.Start);

    Application.Run();
}

static void Log(string text, EventArgs e)
{
    lock(loglock)
    {
        // write to file
    }
}
```

Added: Also if you want to manipulate a control you should use Invoke as always.